# In pyspark, how to loop filter function through a column of data frame?

Tags: python, pyspark, udf

This is the data I have:

```
**name** **movie**
jason        a
jason        b
jason        c
mike         a
mike         b
bruce        a
bruce        c
ryan         b
```

my goal is to make this

```
**name** **# of moive**
jason       a,b,c
mike         a,b
bruce        a,c
ryan          b
```

I am using pyspark and try to use UDF to do this staff. I defined this function and spark gave me a error because it calls the basic functions 'filter', which makes a problem starting a new worker(correct me if it does not).

My logic is first use a filter to make subsets and then the number of rows would be the number of movies. And after this I make a new column with this UDF.

```
def udf(user_name):
    return df.filter(df['name'] == user_name).select('movie').dropDuplictes()\
                                    .toPandas['movie'].tolist()

df.withColumn('movie_number', udf(df['name']))
```

but it's not working. Is there a way to make a UDF with basic spark functions?

So I make the name column into a list and loop through the list, but it's super slow I believe this way I did not do distributed computing.

1) My priority is to figure out how to loop through information in one column of pyspark dataframe with basic functions such as `spark_df.filter`.

2) Can we first make the name column into a RDD and then use my UDF to loop through that RDD, so can take the advantage of distributed computing?

3) If I have 2 tables with the same structure(name/movie), but for different years, like 2005 and 2007 can we have an efficient way to make a third table whose structure is:

```
**name** **movie** **in_2005** **in_2007** 
jason        a          1           0
jason        b          0           1
jason        c          1           1
mike         a          0           1
mike         b          1           0
bruce        a          0           0
bruce        c          1           1
ryan         b          1           0
```

1 and 0 means if this guy made comment on the movie in year 2005/2007 or not. and in this case the original tables would be：

2005：

```
**name** **movie**
jason        a
jason        c
mike         b
bruce        c
ryan         b
```

2007

```
**name** **movie**
jason        b
jason        c
mike         a
bruce        c
```

and my idea is to concat the 2 tables together with a 'year' column, and use a pivot table to get the desired structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `groupby` follow by `collect_list` instead of turning the whole dataframe to RDD. You can apply UDF after.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

# toy example dataframe
ls = [
    ['jason', 'movie_1'],
    ['jason', 'movie_2'],
    ['jason', 'movie_3'],
    ['mike', 'movie_1'],
    ['mike', 'movie_2'],
    ['bruce', 'movie_1'],
    ['bruce', 'movie_3'],
    ['ryan', 'movie_2']
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['name', 'movie']))

df_movie = df.groupby('name').agg(func.collect_list(func.col('movie')))
```

Now, this is an example to create `udf` to deal with new column `movies`. I simply give an example on how to calculate length of each row.

```
def movie_len(movies):
    return len(movies)
udf_movie_len = func.udf(movie_len, returnType=StringType())

df_movie.select('name', 'movies', udf_movie_len(func.col('movies')).alias('n_movies')).show()
```

This will give:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------+
| name|              movies|n_movies|
+-----+--------------------+--------+
|jason|[movie_1, movie_2...|       3|
| ryan|           [movie_2]|       1|
|bruce|  [movie_1, movie_3]|       2|
| mike|  [movie_1, movie_2]|       2|
+-----+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question 1 is how to use UDF with basic pyspark functions, I edited my question. What I also want to learn is to slice the dataframe by value in a column and then do transformations on those subsets.

Comment: @Olap, I changed my solution according to your question. Still suggest to use `groupby`. You can apply udf afterwards.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have another question about playing with multiple tables, can you please help? I have updated the question

Comment: By the way, is there, technically, a way to make a list into RDD and then loop through the list with UDF? (I tried but it went through the whole RDD instead of the values) if so, is it doing distributed computing?

Comment: In that case you don't even need UDF cause you can apply function directly to the RDD.

Comment: And yes, it's doing distributed computing if you use `rdd.map(...).map(...)`